How can I hilight or process Unicode characters when pasting to Terminal apps from PDFs?
Sometimes I copy one-line scripts into the terminal from PDF files. Since they are copied from PDFs, sometimes they contain "shady" characters, such as non-breaking spaces or difficult non-ASCII characters.
I’d like to handle this efficiently if possible.
Can these be safely changed or at least highlighted while pasting a command line snippet in to Terminal.app or iTerm2.app?

FOREWORD:

The question above was deleted by the OP while I was working on the following answer.  Not being keen on wasted effort, I managed to copy the OP's original question, and pasted it into the "new question" above. Yes... this is a bit odd  :)


I think what you may be looking for is a CLI utility called iconv. Inconveniently, iconv requires "from" and "to" argument declarations (ref man iconv) of the encoding type (e.g. UTF-8, ascii, unicode, etc)... and AFAIK, "shady" is not a recognized encoding type :) However - the encoding type may be determined from another CLI utility called file. Still more inconveniently, both iconv and file specify that the input be contained in a file  :/
Your question intrigued me as it seems a reasonable thing to do; i.e. C&P from PDF to CLI. So I spent a few minutes wrangling with iconv and file to get the following answer; an answer which does not require you to C&P your PDF strings into a file. <caveat>This works on my Ventura Mac under zsh, but it's been tested nowhere else.</caveat>
You've not provided an example, and I was unable to find any malfunctioning PDF code strings in a brief search. So - instead, I found this string in a French-language PDF on Python programming:

print("Numéro de boucle", i)

So - first we'll need to run this string through file to determine the encoding (note the use of the "dash" -: a reference to stdin in lieu of a proper filename):
echo "print("Numéro de boucle", i)" | file -
/dev/stdin: Unicode text, UTF-8 text

So - the string was encoded in UTF-8. Now let's convert the string to ASCII from UTF-8 using iconv:

NOTE: The //translit option is not addressed in the macOS version of man iconv, but it still works (?!). It is used as a flag to tell iconv to transliterate the output to the command line. Another option is to ignore the non-ascii character(s): //ignore

echo "print("Numéro de boucle", i)" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
print(Num'ero de boucle, i)

And so you may be wondering, "Why did it add the extra ' character"??. That's a good question, and perhaps the answer is here. Apple may be using utf-8-mac instead of utf-8. Which I guess would be OK if they had bothered to reflect that in their implementation of iconv! In fact, there is a UTF8-MAC encoding listed in the output of iconv --list - but it doesn't improve the transliteration:
echo 'print("Numéro de boucle", i)' | iconv -f utf8-mac -t ascii//translit
print("Num'ero de boucle", i)  

echo 'print('Numéro de boucle', i)' | iconv -f utf-8-mac -t ascii//translit
print(Num'ero de boucle, i)

As written, the iconv utility for macOS Ventura cannot properly convert all utf-8 characters to ASCII. It converts the ones it can, and issues an error (or inserts inappropriate characters) for the others. To get a "best effort" from iconv you can add the -c option, causing iconv to simply drop the characters it cannot convert.
As an experiment: If you have a reasonably current Linux box handy, you can try iconv on the example phrase here. When I tried this on my Linux systems (two versions of Debian; 'bookworm' & 'bullseye'), I found that iconv did a perfectly correct and proper 'transliteration' (//TRANSLIT) of the example used in this answer (and several others); i.e. no extra ' character.
These results could be improved with a sed "filter":
echo 'print("Numéro de boucle", i)' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 , ( )]//g'

But having to use sed to augment iconv strikes me as an ugly hack - one that should be unnecessary.
And so, iconv seems to work at least some of the time in macOS... hope this helps.

I tried iconv with to remove diacritics (target ASCII; source utf-8).  It left some unchanged, did some incorrectly,  did some correctly, and crashed on some character that was in the files more than once.

@WGroleau: Were you able to replicate my results?

@Seamus, it asked me to complete a quote!  I changed the first part toecho "print(\"Numéro de boucle\", i)" but it still thinks there is an open quote.

oops, I tried to paste the whole thing into Terminal.  When I do only the first line, the output isprint(Num'ero de boucle, i)
iconv: warning: invalid characters: 1

For my use, I needed the diacritics to be removed so é→e.  Not e'  But using your method, I verified that a non-breaking space (U+00A0) is converted to a "regular" space (U+0020).

"translit" is misleading.  If I feed it Greek, instead of transliterating, it says "Illegal byte sequence" (which is not true)

Read it LONG ago when I needed the conversion.  Since it didn't do what I needed, I use othewr methods for my conversions.  tr or perl or even TextEdit, depending on the natuere of the data.

Other options:
If you know which characters are causing problems, you can use perl or tr or others to convert those specific characters.
If you paste the text into a LibreOffice Writer document, a non-breaking space will be shaded light gray.  (Now you DO have a shady character!)
If you paste the text into a graphic, an OCR program can turn it back into a text file.  tesseract is a decent free one, but there are others both free and paid.  Advantage of this method is that it goes by what it looks like and is oblivious to the really weird encodings occasionally found in PDF files.
